# Layout in QWidget makes background white when adding a stretch

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlayout

Im using PyQt5 and it's styling system to create a modern looking GUI for my application and i can't seem to get this right.

So i've got a costum titlebar all working. It has 3 parts; a menubar, a label and another menubar that serves as the titlebar buttons for closing, min- and maximizing. 
I need this titlebar to be a light grey color, but as you can see in the image below, there is white space between the elements.

What it is now:

[image]

What is should be:

[image]

When you run the example below, you can see that between the labels there is some empty space. Even though the labels are inside a box without styling, the styling is set on the widget.

```py
#### PyQt imports....
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QMenuBar, QApplication,
                            QLabel, QVBoxLayout)
#### Python imports....
import sys

#### Class for sampleWindow....
class sampleWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        #### Some window settings....
        self.setWindowTitle('Sample Program')
        self.setGeometry(400, 300, 1000, 500)

        ######## THE SAME PROBLEM BUT THIS TIME NOT IN A QMENUBAR ########
        #### Creating the widget and it's layout....
        parentLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        parentWidget = QWidget()

        #### Creating the elements....
        sampleLabelLeft = QLabel('left')
        sampleLabelCenter = QLabel('center')
        sampleLabelRight = QLabel('right')

        #### Setting alignment for the elements....
        sampleLabelLeft.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        sampleLabelCenter.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        sampleLabelRight.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)

        #### Adding the elements to the parentLayout....
        parentLayout.addWidget(sampleLabelLeft)
        parentLayout.addWidget(sampleLabelCenter)
        parentLayout.addWidget(sampleLabelRight)

        #### Setting parentLayout as layout for parentWidget....
        parentWidget.setLayout(parentLayout)

        #### Set styling for elements....
        self.setStyleSheet('QWidget{background:blue;} QLabel{background:red;}')

        #### Setting some a box to put parentWidget in so it can be set as the main layout....
        mainBox = QVBoxLayout()
        mainBox.addStretch()
        mainBox.addWidget(parentWidget)
        mainBox.addStretch()
        mainBox.setContentsMargins(200,200,200,200)
        self.setLayout(mainBox)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
sampleWindow = sampleWindow()
sampleWindow.show()
app.exec()
```

So after this i set the background color of the QWidget to a bit of a light grey and the stretches are ignored.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: provide a [MRE]

Comment: @eyllanesc I've updated the example code which you can now run if you have pyqt5 installed.

Comment: I have executed the code you provide: https://imgur.com/a/4qsEcNU and it has nothing to do with the image you provide, you could place an image of what you get with that code and what you want to obtain.

Comment: @eyllanesc i've edited your screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/kC59Vf4

Comment: @eyllanesc It's the same idea ass the titlebar. Only i've simplified it massively. I made the background blue and the labelbackground red so that the difference pops out. The empty space between the labels shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the layout has a style-dependent [`spacing`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#spacing-prop), so the solution for your case is to set it to 0:

```
# ...
parentLayout = QHBoxLayout()
parentLayout.setSpacing(0)
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting a background widget solved the problem:

```py
parentWidget = QWidget()
label_background = QLabel(parentWidget)
label_background.setFixedSize(1920, 1080)
```